# "Expectation exists" vs "Expectation is finite"

Tags: probability-theory, notation, expected-value

Are the statements

- "Expectation exists"
- "Expectation is finite"

equivalent? If not, could someone please provide a counterexample.

In case it's relevant, I don't know measure theory, but am confortable with probability theory & statistics at the undergraduate level.

Comment: In the fields where I work, people often say "the expected value of so-and-so is infinite" (think the [St Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)), which implies that the expected value could exist without being finite.  But I rarely hear someone say "the expected value of so-and-so exists and is finite."  The explicit assertion of existence seems to connote finiteness.  I'm curious to see what others say.

Comment: According to Durett, the expectation exist if $\mathbb E[X^+]<\infty $ or $\mathbb E[X^-]<\infty $. And is finite if both are $<\infty $. I used $X^+=\max\{X,0\}$ and $X^-=-\min\{X,0\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent, but this is somewhat a matter of opinion. There are three classes of random variables:

1. Variables with finite expected value.
2. Variables with infinite expected value. (This could be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$).
3. Variables whose expectation does not exist.

An example of variable in class (2) is the St. Petersburg random variable, which is equal to $2^k$ with probability $2^{-k}$ for $k\ge 1$. Another example is, letting $X_i$ be an iid sequence of random variables equal to $\pm1$ with equal probabilities, the random variable $\tau$ equal to the smallest positive integer for which $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_\tau=1$.

For variables in class (3), there is the Cauchy distribution with pdf proportional to $\frac1{1+x^2}$.

The question is whether or not you consider variables in category (2) to have an expectation which "exists" or not. I say the expectation exists, so that an expectation can exist but not be finite. However, I think some people disagree, just like there is disagreement as to whether
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{x^2}
$$
is either non-existent, or existent and equal to $+\infty$. I think most professional mathematicians have no qualms saying the limit exists, but it is often taught in entry level calculus courses that such limits do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is the Cauchy distribution. It is symmetric around $0$ but both tails of the distribution are 'too' heavy:
$$
\begin{align}
E[X]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\cdot\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} x\cdot\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{0}^{\infty} x\cdot\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d} x \\
&=\infty -\infty
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you saying that for Cauchy - expectation does exist, even though it's infinite?

Comment: It is infinite minus infinite which is undefined.

Comment: That is a classic example of "the expected value doesn't exist".

Comment: So, 3 cases are possible:
1) Doesn't exist
2) Exists & infinite
3) Exists & finite?

Comment: I would say that it is the case (although I don't view 2) and 3) as different but that is just a personal thing)

Answer (score 1):

*Contra* Stan Tendijck's answer, the Cauchy distribution's mean doesn't exist because $\infty-\infty$ is undefined (technically, it's an indeterminate form). However, the *modulus* of a Cauchy-distributed variable has a mean, but that mean is infinite. So no, a mean existing isn't equivalent to its being finite. In fact whenever $X$ has finite mean but infinite variance it's because $X^2$ has infinite mean. An example is when $X=\sqrt{|Y|}$ with a Cauchy $Y$.